# How do I set up an SSL connection using catalyst web framework?

Tags: ssl, catalyst

According to this site: http://search.cpan.org/~mramberg/Catalyst-Plugin-RequireSSL-0.07/lib/Catalyst/Plugin/RequireSSL.pm
It's as easy as this:

```
 # in MyApp.pm
    use Catalyst qw/
        RequireSSL
    /;
    __PACKAGE__->config(
        require_ssl => {
            remain_in_ssl => 0,
            no_cache => 0,
            detach_on_redirect => 1,
        },
    );
    __PACKAGE__->setup;


    # in any controller methods that should be secured
    $c->require_ssl;
```

However, I am running the app using the built in MyApp_server.pl . And when I follow those instructions I get an SSL connection error Error code: ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

I'm guessing that the MyApp_server.pl doesn't support SSL, or there is more that I need to do to configure it.

Can I set up an SSL connection using nginx? I can find now instructions on how to do this. Can this be done with Apache?

Frankly, I was really hoping to be able to deploy this app with the built in server, but SSL encryption is required for all of my pages.

Thanks for any help that you can provide!

PS This app is running on my personal computer (OSX) behind a firewall, but the intention is to deploy it on a linux server behind a firewall.

Comment: There's already a server process listening on www.mydomain.com: `$ openssl s_client -connect www.mydomain.com:443`. You need to shut down the existing service. *"I get ... `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`"* - that does not sound right. I can connect to the service fine. You should be getting an error about the port being in use.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I can see that my original example was confusing. I am not actually using www.mydomain.com to serve these pages. I did not realize that there was an actual mydomain.com out there and I thought that was an obvious example to use. In any case, I don't want to have a seperate URL for non ssl and ssl connections so I removed the references to www.<my actual domain>.com from the configuration code anyway. I've edited the code example to reflect this.